# 500 internal server error when try to include wp-load.php in codeigniter site

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I have setup a Wordpress blog at `www.example.com/blog` and a Codeigniter site at `www.example.com`. I am trying to display recent post from blog to my Codeigniter site. To do it, I included the `wp-load.php` file using

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-load.php');

   // require_once('../app/blog/wp-load.php');
                         $args = array(
                              // 'cat' => 3, // Only source posts from a specific category
                              'posts_per_page' => 4 // Specify how many posts you'd like to display
                              );
                              $latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );  
                              if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
                                while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
                                $latest_posts->the_post(); ?>
                             <marquee align="top" behavior="scroll" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" direction="up" scrolldelay="200" ><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> 
                            <li>

                              <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                                <span class="post_thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></span>
                              <?php } ?>
                              <span class="post_title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                            </a>
                            <!--span class="post_time">Posted on <?php the_time('l jS F, Y') ?></span-->
                            <?php //the_excerpt(); ?>
                          </li> 
                          </marquee >
                        <? } 
                            } else {
                            echo '<p>There are no posts available</p>';
                          }
                          wp_reset_postdata(); 
                        ?>
```

but throws an internal server error.
Do I have to change the file permission? Please help. The site is hosted by Godaddy.

**Error detail :**

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the
>   error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have
>   caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never include any Wordpress file in your main website as it can lead to many errors. Instead, use Codeigniter's second database connection to connect to your Wordpress database.
Searching for [get wordpress posts from database to codeigniter](https://www.google.com/search?q=get+wordpress+posts+from+database+to+codeigniter) I have found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/fernandoporazzi/6020733) and [this article](https://arjunphp.com/retrieve-data-database-codeigniter/). The following code is taken from this article. Note that this code is for Codeigniter 2 and the code is not tested. But I have dealt with many databases in Codeigniter before, just ask if you find any trouble.

**a. add a different settings data in your `application/config/database.php` file along side with your main website database settings:**

```
$db['wordpress']['hostname'] = "wordpress_db_host"; // database host
$db['wordpress']['username'] = "wordpress_db_username"; // db user name
$db['wordpress']['password'] = "wordpress_db_password"; // db user password
$db['wordpress']['database'] = "wordpress_db"; // database name
```

**b. build a Wordpress model in `application/models/wordpress_model.php`:**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) die ('No direct script access allowed!');

class Wordpress_Model extends CI_Model
{
    function getPosts()
    {
        $this->load->database('wordpress', TRUE); // load database

        // get the wordpress posts, customize it as you like
        $this->wordpress->select("post_id, post_title, post_content");
        $this->wordpress->from('post_tbl');
        $this->wordpress->limit(5);
        $query = $this->wordpress->get();
        $data['posts'] = $query->result();

        $this->load->view('wordpress_posts_view', $data); // load the view file , we are passing $data array to view file
    }
}
```

**c. create the view file in `application/views/wordpress_posts_view.php`:**

```
<h4>Display Records From Database Using Codeigniter</h4>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Post Id</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Post Title</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($posts as $post){?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $post->post_id;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $post->post_title;?></td>
        </tr>    
    <?php }?>  
</table>
```

**d. now, you can call all this in any Codeigniter controller:**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) die ('No direct script access allowed!');

class Homepage extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('wordpress_model');

        $data['wordpress_html_posts'] = $this->wordpress_model->getPosts();
        print_r($data['wordpress_html_posts']);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering but still it is throwing internal server error, i am unable to find what i am doing wrong? or its a problem with godaddy ?

Comment: Does your main website `www.example.com` and blog `www.example.com/blog` work on their own, without changing the code?

Comment: yes.
 whenever i try to include any file from another application or folder it is throwing an error

Comment: So, you are saying that the main website (using codeigniter) is working without modification and when you include the model as I posted above, you get the error? That seems very unlikely.

Comment: The main website is working even if i did modification, it is throwing an error only for that controller ex: www.example.com/wordpress

Comment: When asked you above, you said that the blog is working fine. So basically, your problem is that your blog doesn't work. It has nothing to do with the main website.

Comment: thanks its working now. Just one more question how can i use wordpress core functions in codeigniter site? Like i want display all categories in my codeigniter site ?

Comment: It's up to you if you want to have problems by integrating Wordpress core into Codeigniter. For example, the [site_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) function collides with [site_url](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) from codeigniter resulting in a fatal error. This is only one case. I recommend using the same database connection as I used it in my answer to get the wordpress categories. And, in my opinion, is by far an easier method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79757/discussion-between-dennis-and-machineaddict).